# Draw a plane in fragment shader using determinant?

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader, linear-algebra

I'd like to use the determinant of a matrix to draw a plane in the fragment shader. But I don't understand how to come up with the matrix.
Let's say that I have 3 points that lie on the plane: A, B, and C. I don't know how to combine them into the matrix I need.

// "point" represents the current pixel in the shader.
I tried this:

```
mat4 matrix = mat4(vec4(A.x, A.y, A.z, 1.0), 
                    vec4(B.x, B.y, B.z, 1.0), 
                    vec4(C.x, C.y, C.z, 1.0), 
                    vec4(point.x, point.y, point.z, 1.0));
    float result = determinant(matrix);
    
    if (result == 0.0) {
        // Color the plane.
        ALBEDO = vec3(.3, .3, .3);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you show us an example of the kind of visual output you're trying to create?

Comment: @DMGregory I'd just like every point that lies on the plane to be this color: vec3(.3, .3, .3). The output would literally look like a flat plane

Comment: What's the geometry input here? Are you trying to do something like raymarching, where you render a fullscreen quad and then sculpt the virtual geometry in the math? If so, what you've shown here is not the way to do it. Try taking a step back and editing your question to explain the context where you're trying to use this shader and why - that can help us narrow down what solutions would be appropriate for that use case.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks. There actually is no use case. This is just a problem I came up with to help me understand how determinants work. I read that you can use the determinant to figure out if a point lies on a plane so I figured that I should be able to draw a plane using determinants, but I cant seem to do that. I suspect I'm inputting the matrix wrong. I'm confused about how to convert 4 vectors into a matrix.For the determinant should the vectors become rows or columns in the new matrix? And when I create a mat4() are the vector parameters rows or columns?

Comment: I wouldn't use a determinant for this at all. A single 4-vector and a dot product is enough to define a plane. That's why I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what you're trying to do. Do you have a particular source you were reading from that might help fill in this context?

Comment: My real use case is to figure out if a point is above or below a plane.  I lost my source, but I thought I would need a determinant for that? I guess I should have asked that question directly. Would a determinant be the best approach for figuring out if a point is above or below the plane?

Comment: `Dot(point to check - point on plane, plane normal) > 0` would be a more conventional route. Want to edit your question to ask "How to determine whether a point is above or below a plane?" ?